# Trace theorems and Sobolev Spaces in unbounded domains

Tags: sobolev-spaces, functional-inequalities, trace-map

I am studying trace theorems in unbounded domains, but I do not find any results about what is the situation in unbounded domains.

I am interested in the following domain:
$$
(-\infty, a)\cup(b,+\infty),
$$
where $a\neq b$. There exist trace theorems for this kinds of domains ?

Comment: Your domain is 1 dimensional? What is there to say about the trace theorem then? (The boundary is just two points...) Do you mean something else?

Comment: yes, I need understand which is the situation in this case. @WillieWong

Answer (score 1):

Since the boundary of the domain is just 2 points, there's no concern with "integrability" of the function on the boundary.

Instead, the only concern is whether there is a well-defined boundary value of your function. And this follow from Morrey-Sobolev (or since we are in one-dimension: fundamental theorem of calculus), which states that $W^{k,p} \hookrightarrow C^0$ (in the one dimensional setting) for all $k,p \geq 1$. In this case the continuous representative can be extended continuously to the boundary, and hence the boundary value is well-defined.

(I expect for reasonable definitions of fractional Sobolev spaces you can extend this also to $W^{s,p}$ with $s > 1/p$ and $p > 1$.)